# Trying to align a text object to shape

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, alignment, maps

I am using illustrator cs6.
I am making a transit map for bus stops. I want to make sure that all the stop names are at the same distance from the stop symbol across the map, or at least on one route.
I can align all the stop names vertically or horizontally, but how to do it when the route is diagonal?

I have attached an img of what I am trying to do:

I want to align all the stop names to the stops so that each stop name is the same distance from its respective stop

[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would....

- Draw a diagonal line offset from the stops.
- Convert it to a guide (View > Guides > Make Guides)
- Draw a guide that bisects the stop horizontally
- Align the text right, placing the type anchor on the line and the top of the type on the horizontal guide
  [image]

For diagonals, none of the Alignment buttons are going to be of much help. You have to do it manually. You could measure distances to determine placement, or use the method here for a more visual placement.

Comment: Yes this would help since I don't want to design stops again. I've already got all the stops, (about 150 of them), so no use making new ones all over again Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is design one element, with the text set to Align Right, next to the rounded rectangle. Select both and group them using CTRL+G

Copy and paste the group for the next station, and edit the text.

That way the text of each item will be exactly in the same position.

[image: Example using Groups]

Comment: This is the better option... especially if there happened to be curved lines to follow

Comment: Of course. I didn't think of the text-align right option. This makes good sense. Still getting the hang of simple stuff in Illustrator. Thanks!